# Not able to download file from api using ngx file saver angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 12 and ngxx file saver. I am trying to download file from api response. I am getting response as 200 OK but I am still not able to download file.I know it has something to do with response type json as blob but I dont know how to use it and where to use it. Below is my code.

Component.ts

```
 downloadAppointmentConsent(appointmentConsent: any) {
    this.consentService
      .downloadAppointmentConsent(appointmentConsent.id)
      .then((response: any) => {
        this.fileSaverService.save(response, 'AppointmentConsent.pdf');
      });
  }
```

Service.ts

```
 downloadAppointmentConsent(appointmentConsetId: number) {
    const apiUrl = '/api/consents/' + appointmentConsetId + '/download';
    return this.apiService.get(
      apiUrl,
      'Unable to download to file.',
      false,
      this.httpHelperService.getTenantHttpOptions()
    );
  }
```

HelperService.ts

```
 getTenantHttpOptions(businessId?: any) {
    businessId = businessId ? businessId : this.businessId;
    if (!businessId) {
      businessId =
        this.localStorageService.readStorage('currentUser')?.businessId;
    }
    const httpOptions = {
      'X-TenantID': '' + businessId
    };

    return httpOptions;
  }
```

Apiservice.ts

```
get(
    url: string,
    errorMsg: any = '',
    doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean = false,
    headerOptions: any = {},
    loaderContinue?: any
  ) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const options = await this.getHeader(
        headerOptions,
        doNotSendAuthorizationParam
      );
      this.http
        .get(`${this.hostUrl}${url}`, options)
        .pipe(
          map((res) => {
            if (!loaderContinue) {
              // this.stopLoader();
            }
            return res;
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {
            resolve(res);
          },
          (err) => {
            if (errorMsg) {
              this.handleError(errorMsg);
            } else {
              this.handleError(err);
            }

            reject(err);
          }
        );
    });
  }

  async getHeader(headerOptions: any, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean) {
    const headerParams: any = {};
    const token: any = await this.localStorageService.readStorage('currentUser')
      ?.idToken;
    //const token = 'asdfsqkjdshgakdhdJasjghHSAJDKSDJHKJJ';

    if (doNotSendAuthorizationParam !== true && token) {
      headerParams.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    if (headerOptions) {
      Object.assign(headerParams, headerOptions);
    }
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(headerParams);
    return { headers };
  }
```

I am getting error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad.Http failure during parsing for https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/6480/download"**

Below is screenshot of my preview
[image]

Comment: what does apiService.get accepts? and what is httpOptions in getTenantHttpOptions?

Comment: httpOptions  is just we are adding x-tenantid to every api request
And api service.get is common get method for all the api which return the promise

Comment: tenantid, that seams familiar terminology from a org xD

Comment: basically tenantId is u can assume  businessId.
{responseType: 'blob'} I know this needs to be passed. But where do i pass this.
In header, in body ?

Comment: I tried tis but not working

 getTenantHttpOptionsinHeadersForFile() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('X-TenantID', '' + this.businessId)
      .set('responseType', 'blob' as 'json');

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }

Comment: I am not from any of above, I am from INDIA , working in crest data systems.

Answer (score 0):

In httpOptions you want to get response as blob.which can be done like :-

```
this.httpClient.get('url', {responseType: 'blob'});
```

in your case like below :-

```
 downloadAppointmentConsent(appointmentConsetId: number) {
    const apiUrl = '/api/consents/' + appointmentConsetId + '/download';
    return this.apiService.get(
      apiUrl,
      'Unable to download to file.',
      false,
      {...this.httpHelperService.getTenantHttpOptions(), responseType: 'blob'}
    );
  }
```

Comment: This doesnt work in my current code.

Comment: what do you receive in response from that api?

Comment: I mean it is the way but I am not able to make it work in my implementation. I got you what you are saying. But my point is where should I add the above peice of code in my implementation

Comment: you should add it in getTenantHttpOptions response.

Comment: I tried this but not working 

 getTenantHttpOptionsinHeadersForFile() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('X-TenantID', '' + this.businessId)
      .set('responseType', 'blob' as 'json');

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }

Comment: Now after your updated answer the status changed from 200 to unknown error
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"

Comment: any other error in console?

Comment: Updated my question, Error is unknown error, status code is 0, apart from that no other error, only api failure

Comment: undo this and please tell when you are getting 200 what you can see in preview tab of dev tools

Comment: undoing this, getting Something very unusual, unreadable data, I think like encoded file

Comment: just confirming that it isn't the base64 string. if its base64 string, try using responseType: 'text' instead of blob.

Comment: if you can show me a screenshot i can tell

Comment: Response type text wont work, how ever it will work if I do below way

  public downloadAppointmentConsent(appointmentConsetId: any): Observable<Blob> {
        let url = this.httpHelperService.getApiUrl() + '/api/consents/' + appointmentConsetId + '/download';
        return this.http.get<Blob>(url, { 'responseType': 'blob' as 'json' });
    }

Comment: unless you show screenshot of preview, its impossible to answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244406/discussion-between-tyler-and-aakash-garg).